# Hide seekbar in exoplayer leanback

Tags: leanback

mMediaPlayerGlue.setSeekEnabled(false);

is not hiding the seekbar like the documentation says. Is this bugged or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is, and once again due to the lack of ability to work with these classes was reflection of PlaybackSupportFragment and editing the views visibility there.

Comment: do you know or have a sample?